# redbean php error - declaration of RedBeanPHP\OODBBean:offsetGet() must be compatible with that of ArrayAccess:offsetGet()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i built a web application using redbeanphp version 4.3

everything worked on localhost, but when I moved everything to my host, I got the error above.

the errors occurs

```
class OODBBean implements\IteratorAggregate,\ArrayAccess,\Countable
```

php version 5.3.3
mysql version 5.1.61

any idea how to solve it?

Comment: https://github.com/ikoniaris/kippo-graph/issues/23

Comment: I did use the file from redbeanphp's website

Answer (score 0):

Find for

```
public function &offsetGet( $offset )
```

and replace it with

```
public function offsetGet( $offset )
```

because ArrayAccess::offsetGet is not defined with reference